# DataSearch from Reactivesearch left align autocomplete suggestions

Tags: reactivesearch

Trying to left align suggestions from the dropdown list in the DataSearch component from ReactiveSearch for autocomplete feature. They currently display in the middle of the dropdown.

[Here](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#styles) is what it says to do

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="query-index"
  url="http://localhost:9200">
  <DataSearch
    componentId="SearchSensor"
    dataField={["suggestions"]}
    className="autocomplete"
    iconPosition="right"
    innerclassName={{
    list: "text-item"
    }}
    />
  </ReactiveBase>
```

and then in my css

```
.autocomplete .text-item {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

However, its not working, still displaying in the middle, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: They should appear left aligned by default, perhpas some styles leaking in. Could you create a code-sandbox or demo? [Reference](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#demo)

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani - yea your were right, some styles were a bit messed up. aligning to the left now.

Comment: Cool, could you close this question since it might it might confuse someone

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani - sorry, unexpectedly away from the office for a few days. Closing. And thanks for all the answers!!